# Will a carriage return be correct or not for the PSR-2?

Tags: php, psr-2

I use to create my classes like this, with an extra blank line after the closing } (here line 9):

```
<?php
class myClassName
{
    public function index()
    {
        // my code here
    }
}
// here
```

This helps me to find the functions list when I use my favorite coding tool, notepad++
but i've heard that it can be an error on some PSR validators.
Reading the [PSR-2 coding style guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), I don't find anything about this one.

Does this cause errors in validators?

Comment: Seems to be good since it's line break for EOF (End Of File) and it's recommanded.

Comment: héhéhé ... chariot est 'carriage' en english :)